# spark.default.parallelism for Parallelize RDD defaults to 2 for spark submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Spark standalone cluster with a master and 2 worker nodes 4 cpu core on each worker. Total 8 cores for all workers.

When running the following via spark-submit (spark.default.parallelism is not set)

```scala
val myRDD = sc.parallelize(1 to 100000)
println("Partititon size - " + myRDD.partitions.size)
val totl = myRDD.reduce((x, y) => x + y)
println("Sum - " + totl)
```

It returns value 2 for partition size.

When using spark-shell  by connecting to spark standalone cluster the same code returns correct partition size 8.

What can be the reason ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`spark.default.parallelism` defaults to the number of all cores on all machines.  The parallelize api has no parent RDD to determine the number of partitions, so it uses the `spark.default.parallelism`.

When running `spark-submit`, you're probably running it locally. Try submitting your `spark-submit` with the same start up configs as you do the spark-shell.

Pulled this from the documentation:

```
spark.default.parallelism
```

For distributed shuffle operations like `reduceByKey` and `join`, the largest number of partitions in a parent RDD. For operations like parallelize with no parent RDDs, it depends on the cluster manager:

> Local mode: number of cores on the local machine
>
> Mesos fine grained mode: 8
>
> Others: total number of cores on all executor nodes or 2, whichever is larger

Default number of partitions in RDDs returned by transformations like `join`, `reduceByKey`, and parallelize when not set by user.

Comment: Yes submitted it with same startup configs and can see the job in web ui and history server.. looks like it has been observed by others as well http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Parallelize-on-spark-context-td18327.html#a18332
http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/default-parallelism-in-trunk-td1100.html#a1148

Comment: Just edited my post, but it should default to the total number of cores of your executors.

Answer (score 0):

spark.default.parallelism was introduced with RDD hence this property is only applicable to RDD. Whereas spark.sql.shuffle.partitions was introduced with DataFrame and it only works with DataFrame, the default value for this configuration set to 200.

For DataFrame, wider transformations like groupBy(), join() triggers the data shuffling hence the result of these transformations results in partition size same as the value set in spark.sql.shuffle.partitions. Prior to using these operations, use the below code to get the desired partitions (change the value according to your need)
Try this
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",100)